# Mac terminal selection conflict with vim

Tags: mac, vim

when I use vim on mac I got the problem that some times, Mac terminal's block selection color will come out and cover part of the screen, as you see in the picture. It's pretty annoying. Does anyone know how to get ride of it.

[image: See the light blue area on top]

Comment: Are you using [iterm2](https://www.iterm2.com/) or the built in Mac terminal?

Comment: built in Mac terminal

Comment: Use Vim's built-in visual selection and yank/put instead of your terminal emulator's.